# Ending an email in Japanese to your sensei?

Tags: email

I am learning Japanese, and was wondering how to end an email to my Japanese Sensei?

Like something similar to Regards or Thank You. A more respectful way to end an email.

Comment: Depends what the email was about, your relationship with them, how close you are, etc...

Comment: @Ash Seems pretty complicated. What about a more respectful way to end an email?

Answer (score 2):

You could always try the simple (どうぞ)よろしくお願い致します. The bits around it might change based on context, but at a basic level it's just fine, and I'm pretty sure in most situations it would be there regardless.

The verdict seems to be out on the appropriateness of どうぞ. There are sites that say it is acceptable to use it, but user @Rilakkuma has personal experience being told not to. I'd imagine that in formal business settings this might be more of an issue than in a casual email to your professor, though.

Comment: どうぞ is usually not used in formal emails, so just 宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @Rilakkuma I do see a どうぞ variation listed on this [ビジネスマナー](http://kakikata.dkrht.com/mail1/mkihon00800.html) site. With regard to 致します, would you say it's best to use that with a professor over します?

Comment: 先生に対して・・・「どうぞよろしくお願いします、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします、よろしくお願いします、よろしくお願いいたします」･･･どれでもいいと思う・・・

Comment: @ssb although I agree どうぞ is sometimes listed I've been told several times not to use it in business emails working with Japanese companies, because it "is suitable for conversation, but not email".

Comment: @Rilakkuma へえ、そうなんだ？知らなかったなぁ･･･

Comment: I guess the argument against どうぞ not being suited is about it being too casual. You could use なにとぞ for example in this case, it's common and polite enough. However I'd personally still advise against it as I find it too pedantic in the context of a greeting. But a lot of native speakers would still go for it.